# error while compiling camera1394

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, camera1394, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am trying to compile [camera1394](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394) (master branch)from source. However, I got many error like these:

```
dev_camera1394.cpp:(.text+0xe28): undefined reference to `ros::console::initializeLogLocation(ros::console::LogLocation*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::console::levels::Level)'
dev_camera1394.cpp:(.text+0xe62): undefined reference to `ros::console::setLogLocationLevel(ros::console::LogLocation*, ros::console::levels::Level)'
dev_camera1394.cpp:(.text+0xe6e): undefined reference to `ros::console::checkLogLocationEnabled(ros::console::LogLocation*)'
```

I am using [Gumstix Overo](https://www.gumstix.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=256) and its OS is [Linaro](http://www.linaro.org/).

Then I try to build camera1394 (groovy branch) with rosmake, but I got following error:

```
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesmera1394: 721.5 sec ]         [ 1 Active 8/9 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Scanning dependencies of target rospack_gencfg_real
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/build'
  [  7%] Built target rospack_gencfg_real
  make[3]: Entering directory `/root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/build'
  Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/build'
  [  7%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Entering directory `/root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/build'
  Scanning dependencies of target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/build'
  [  7%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/build'
  Scanning dependencies of target camera1394_node
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/build'
  [ 15%] Building CXX object src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/camera1394_node.cpp.o
  In file included from /root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/src/nodes/driver1394.h:44:0,
               from /root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/src/nodes/camera1394_node.cpp:38:
  /root/catkin_ws/install/include/driver_base/driver.h: In static member function ‘static const string& driver_base::Driver::getStateName(driver_base::Driver::state_t)’:
  /root/catkin_ws/install/include/driver_base/driver.h:238:14: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
  [ 23%] Building CXX object src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/modes.cpp.o
  [ 30%] Building CXX object src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/format7.cpp.o
  [ 38%] Building CXX object src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/features.cpp.o
  [ 46%] Building CXX object src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/dev_camera1394.cpp.o
  [ 53%] Building CXX object src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/driver1394.cpp.o
  In file included from /root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/src/nodes/driver1394.h:44:0,
               from /root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/src/nodes/driver1394.cpp:42:
  /root/catkin_ws/install/include/driver_base/driver.h: In static member function ‘static const string& driver_base::Driver::getStateName(driver_base::Driver::state_t)’:
  /root/catkin_ws/install/include/driver_base/driver.h:238:14: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
  c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
  Please submit a full bug report,
  with preprocessed source if appropriate.
  See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
  make[3]: *** [src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/driver1394.cpp.o] Error 4
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/build'
  make[2]: *** [src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/rosbuild_ws/camera1394/build'
```

I have successfully compiled all the dependencies of camera1394.

Can anyone give me some hints why these error happened?

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57698/error-while-compiling-camera1394/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-11**:
Now you are getting an internal compiler error. What compiler version are you using?

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-03-11**:
Do you mean gcc? I have gcc with version 4.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first linking error:

```
dev_camera1394.cpp:(.text+0xe28): undefined reference to `ros::console::initializeLogLocation(ros::console::LogLocation*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::console::levels::Level)'
dev_camera1394.cpp:(.text+0xe62): undefined reference to `ros::console::setLogLocationLevel(ros::console::LogLocation*, ros::console::levels::Level)'
dev_camera1394.cpp:(.text+0xe6e): undefined reference to `ros::console::checkLogLocationEnabled(ros::console::LogLocation*)'
```

Occurs because the package `camera1394` is not linking against `rosconsole`, I think that this unlikely to be a complete error log, but instead occurred when `rosconsole` could not be found by `rosmake`.

The second error is because a rosbuild package's name is based on its folder name. In this case a dynamic reconfigure file is declaring its package to be `camera1394`:

```
PACKAGE='camera1394'
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest(PACKAGE)
```

But cannot find it at build time:

```
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: camera1394
```

This is because you have the package in the folder `/root/catkin_ws/src/camera1394-groovy-devel/`, making the package name `camera1394-groovy-devel` rather than just `camera1394`.

To resolve this, rename that folder to `camera1394` and rebuild it.

Additionally, you should not be mixing `catkin` and `rosbuild` workspaces, their workspaces are orthogonal, instead you should have a folder structure like this:

```
catkin_ws/
     src/
         catkin_pkg1/
         catkin_pkg2/
         ...
     install/
         setup.bash
         ...
rosbuild_ws/
    setup.bash
    ...
    rosbuild_stack1
    rosbuild_stack2
```

Where you build the `catkin_ws` with `catkin_make install`, then `source catkin_ws/install/setup.bash` before creating and building the `rosbuild_ws` workspace.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-03-11**:
Hi William, I made a new directory rosbuild_ws and add it to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Then I move the camera1394-groovy-devel to rosbuild_ws and rename it to camera1394. But I got a new error while compiling. I update that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The **camera1394** `master` branch is still being ported to catkin, but not working yet.

The `groovy-devel` branch is the current 1.8.1 release, which should work with rosbuild. See the [README file](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/blob/master/README.rst).

**EDIT**: Your compiler is reporting a fatal internal error. GCC 4.6.3 works fine for me on x86_64 with Precise.

Maybe there is a problem with the ARM back-end.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-03-11**:
Hi joq, I got error while compiling groovy-devel. But I noticed that there is a branch called groovy, what's the difference between groovy-devel and groovy? Should I try groovy branch?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-11**:
The `groovy` branch was created by `rosrelease` for the 1.8.1 update. It is identical to `groovy-devel`.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-03-11**:
I am wondering why I can compile camera1394(electric version) but not camera1394(groovy-devel version).

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-11**:
Monitor your memory, gcc will crash sometimes if you run out of memory. If so, try `make -j1` to ensure only one gcc process at a time.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-11**:
What source URL are you using for Electric? I have no idea why that might work but the Groovy version does not. What ROS distro are you running?